# Barracuda Quarantine - Externally Accessible?

Tags: security, barracuda

I manage several Barracuda Spam filters.  When an e-mail is sent through the barracuda to somebody and it seems to have spammy charactertistics but is not clearly spam, the barracuda will place it in the user's quarantine.  Once a day it sends an HTML e-mail notification of all the messages the user currently has in spam, with links to the barracuda applicance.

My question is to those of you who have a Barracuda Spam filter out there... do you make this quarantine page accessible from outside your network?  So if a user clicks on the links in the e-mail from outuside of your network (such as at home) they are still able to access their quarantine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, when we were using the quarantine feature we made this available externally.  We used LDAP authentication and made only the SSL site available, so that the connection was encrypted and not sending login credentials cleartext.

Comment: +1 This is definitely doable using this method.  Make sure the DNS name of the Barracuda is resolvable both internally and externally too (obviously your SSL cert will need to match the name).